# How do I write a function to draw histogram in R?

Tags: r, histogram, function

I want to write a function that takes in the variables from a data frame as arguments and prints the corresponding histogram for that variable in R. I have been trying to make use of hist() function but have been facing trouble calling it from my my own function. How do approach this? Thanks.

For example

attributeHist <- function(attribute){
 hist(dataframe$attribute)
}

I am having trouble referencing the attribute in the data frame which I am passing as arguments within the function. Kindly help.

Comment: Welcome to our site! But please note that pure programming questions are not on-topic here. Antway, you shoyld describe what problems you have when calling hist() from within your own function, as that should be easy, and you probably misunderstood some easy point.  But without you telling us what happened, there is nothing we can do.

Comment: It's easy to call hist from a function, so it's not clear what problem you have. What did you do?

Comment: Use `data.frame[[attribute]]` where `attribute` is a character string.

Comment: In R, you have to be careful about whether the name of a column in a data frame is being treated as a character string or as the name of an object. I find it safest to use character strings, as @Roland suggests.

Comment: Do you really want to have all the optional arguments of `hist` hard-coded since you cannot change any of them?

Comment: Exactly why do you want to write a function? Is it only for plotting several histograms? If so, you should look at e.g. ggplot.